# Why compressed blob values don't change sqlite database size?

Tags: php, sqlite, compression, blob

I have a `.sqlite` **database**:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:db.sqlite");
```

It's **size is 60MB**. It has 1 table. One of this table columns (the only heavy one) holds `BLOB_TEXT` data. I am **trying to compress this column values**:

```
$pdo = $db->query("SELECT id, house_plan FROM houses");
$houses = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$initial_length = 0;
$compressed_length= 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($houses); $i++) {
  $id = $houses[$i]["id"];
  $house_plan = $houses[$i]["house_plan"];
  $compressed = gzcompress($house_plan);

  $initial_length += strlen($house_plan);
  $compressed_length += strlen($compressed);
  flush();

  $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE houses SET house_plan=? WHERE id=" . $id);
  $query->bindParam(1, $compressed, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
  $query->execute();
}
```

Then printing summed initial `BLOB_TEXT` data length and compressed data length (which replaced the initial data in the table):

```
echo "Before: " . $initial_length . ", After: " . $compressed_length;
// Before: 52222553, After: 2577948
```

And their difference in %:

```
echo "Difference: " . (100 - round($compressed_length / $initial_length * 100)) . "%";
// Difference: 95%
```

Afterwards **I check the size of the database, and it's still 60MB**. `BLOB_TEXT` data **difference was 95%, but the size of the database is not changed**.

How that might be? Or what I am doing wrong compressing `BLOB_TEXT`?
I expect database size reduces as well, because this is the only heavy column I have.

Comment: Ran into this today, very helpful @Nik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the compression, the database was filled to about 100 % with data.
After the compression, it contains about 5 % data and about 95 % free space.

Usually, it is a good idea to avoid reducing the file size because the free space will be filled up with new data later anyway.
If you want to re-pack the database, run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

Comment: +1 [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) rebuilds the database, reclaims empty space and reduces the size of the database file.

Comment: I will accept the answer if you enrich it with `$query = $db->prepare("VACUUM"); $query->execute();`, what is definitely going to underline the solution matching my question and the source code in the description.